# jqGrid custom filtering with build in filtering toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the latest jqGrid version and I'm wondering if it's possible to do local filtering with custom rules (see example below). First of all, the filter toolbar can be switched on by applying

`jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', options);`

In the past I implemented this manually (the version I currently use does not support local filtering, so I added this feature according the my needs) and now, after an update to the latest version, I asked myself if jqGrid offers this functionalty by default (Not the local filtering, which it does, but the custom filtering rules) as the functionality impressively increased over the last months. I read the documentation and searched the internet, but did not find a suitable example.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve.

There's a column `First Name` which hold the first name of the persons displayed.

```
Stefan
Stephan
Stephano
Stelios
Philip
Phillip
Philipp
Ivan
Iwan
...
```

Now the user enters `Ste` in the filtering bar for column `First Name` and the result with the default filtering algorithm should be :)

```
Stefan
Stephan
Stephano
Stelios
```

So far so good. But what if I want to display names which are ortographically similar? I want the user to enter `Ste*an*` to only display

```
Stefan
Stephan
Stephano
```

So you see, `*` stands for a wildcard for any character zero or more times. Additionally I want the user to be able to enter `Ste?an*` resulting in

```
Stefan
```

where `?` means any character exactly once. One last requirement is to make the filtering more tolerant and matching not only the hole line (starting and ending, equivalent to regular expressions), but matching the column value if it contains the text entered, i.e. `e*o` matching

```
Stephano
Stelios
```

If you could give me a hint with the `*` wildcard, the other problems should right themselves.

Thanks in advance

Kai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my old answers [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/searching-on-text-field-with-accentued-chars-on-local-datas/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822302/how-to-do-local-search-on-formatted-column-value-in-jqgrid/5822685#5822685) I described how one can implement custom filtering.

If you in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSearchAndSortWithFilter.htm) type for example "ev" in the filter for 'Client' column you will see the following:

[image]

You can easy modify the demo to make for example 'Stephan' and 'Stefan' equivalent.

I personally use mostly `defaultSearch: 'cn'` in the `filterToolbar` options. Together with the usage of `ignoreCase: true` it follow to very good user experience. In my personal opinion such filtering is good enough. More advanced user can use Advanced Searching to create the filter like 'begin with' "Ste" AND 'contains' "an" instead of `Ste*an*`.

Nevertheless you can use idea from [my old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSearchAndSortWithFilter.htm) to overwrite some [internal searching methods](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L90) used by jqGrid.

Comment: Hi Oleg, as this answer partially helped me out, I "accept" it. As our customer wants us to support * and ? we had to add this funcionality on our own. Thanks.