# How to sort numeric column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

In my jqGrid I have a column that has this format: '1.234,678'. I want to sort this column, and I am using this code:

`{name:'ZMENG_SOR_VRKME', index:'ZMENG_SOR_VRKME', width:'5', align:'right', sorttype:'number' }`

Sorting doesn't work. I think that it is not considering .(dot) as thousands, for examples if I have 21,000 - 991,000 - 1.188,000. The results is: 991,000 - 21,000 - 1.188,000.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you should change the format of data filled in the grid. You should use pure numbers as the input and use `formatter: "number"` to include thousands separator in the number. It will be the best way to solve your problem in my opinion. You can use correct language file `grid.locale-XX.js` the thousands separator will be used corresponds the locale. Alternatively you can use `decimalSeparator` and `thousandsSeparator` of `formatoptions` to specify your custom decimal and thousand separators.

Alternatively you can either provide unformatter (`unformat` function described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting)) which converts the text displayed in the cell to the number. I think it should work.

One more possibility is usage of custom sorting. You need define `sorttype` as function which would be return "normalized" version of the data. The "normalized" data will be used instead of original data during sorting. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8001822/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296935/315935) for code examples.

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) provides some standard templates like `template: "integer"`, `number: "number"`, `template: "integerStr"`, `number: "numberStr"` and other. Thus one can use

```js
{name: "ZMENG_SOR_VRKME", width: 50, template: "numberStr" }
```

which would be equivalent to the usage of

```js
{name: "ZMENG_SOR_VRKME", width: 50,
    formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] } }
```

Comment: Tks Oleg, I decide to use pure numbers and format options for my costum formatter and it's works..

Comment: @AmulHarad: You are welcome! If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, then you can use `formatter: "number"` or `formatter: "numberStr"`, which are shout-cuts of [the settings](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.0/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L175-L186). One can easy define his own settings as new column template by extending `$.jgrid.cmTemplate`. Usage of templates makes the code, which uses jqGrid, shorter, better readable and easier to maintain.