# jqGrid not sorting properly on Date object

Tags: jqgrid

We are using jqGrid in local mode and as part of our ajax call the Json result is being modified so that dates are converted into valid JS Date objects.  The problem is that these aren't sorting properly.

My colModel is below:

```
       {
            name: 'reservationTime',
            index: 'reservationTime',
            sorttype: 'date'
        }
```

For the most part they are in "order" but the first is from the middle of the data and half way through is a record from near the beginning.

When I click the header to try to sort it asc/desc it doesn't change at all.  If I sort another field that works fine and when I then sort by my date field it will do the broken sort again but that's it.

Comment: I posted the pool request which will fix the problem (see my UPDATED answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid don't support the `Date` as native datatype in compare operations so I suggest you two ways as the workaround.

1) You can use `sorttype` as function. In the case the function will be called with `Date` parameter and the function can return the string which can be used *instead of* Date in compare operations. For example

```js
sorttype: function (d) {
    if ($.isFunction(d.toISOString)) {
        return d.toISOString();
    }

    return ISODateString(d);
    // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
    function ISODateString(d) {
        function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; }

        return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-'
            + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-'
            + pad(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T'
            + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':'
            + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'
            + pad(d.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z'
    }
}
```

2) You can extend the [_compare](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L294-314) function used internally by jqGrid to support `Date` type. You can use the trick which I described in my [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822685/315935). In case of usage of `_compare` the code will be

```js
var oldFrom = $.jgrid.from;

$.jgrid.from = function (source, initalQuery) {
    var result = oldFrom.call(this, source, initalQuery),
        old_compare = result._compare;
    result._compare = function (a, b, d) {
        if (typeof a === "object" && typeof b === "object" &&
                a instanceof Date && b instanceof Date) {
            if (a < b) { return -d; }
            if (a > b) { return d; }
            return 0;
        }
        return _compare.call(this, a, b, d);
    };
    return result;
};
```

You can insert the code before the usage of jqGrid like I demonstrate it on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DateToSort.htm).

**UPDATED**: I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/279) which fix the problem.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille: the pull request is already merged (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/af9a7da033856a5cd9906574885e778b5c7442fb)) with the main code of jqGrid. So the next version of jqGrid will sort correctly with local data having `Date` type.