# jqGrid client-side search with 'in array' search operator or a custom search function

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, client-side

I am applying client-side search to a jqGrid without the search dialog, but I need to perform the search with a custom search function or a more clever search operator, one of which will essentially do `$.inArray([searchString],[searchField])`.

My grid has `datatype: 'json'` and `loadonce: 'true'` and does not use `multisearch`. The relevant column I want to search has `colModel: [ {name: 'ancestorIds', hidden: true } ]` and it will contain an array of ids like `[1,2,26,42]`.
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492963/jqgrid-client-side-searching), I am initializing the single field search from a click event outside the grid, something like this:

```
var selectedId = $('#selectedId').val();
var $grid = $('#grid');
var postdata = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
$.extend(postdata, {
    filters: '',
    searchField: 'ancestorIds',
    searchOper: 'cn',
    searchString: selectedId
}); 
$grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true, postData: postdata });
$grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
```

This works fine, except if `selectedId` is 2, using `searchOper: 'cn'` will incorrectly return rows which include 26 or 42.  My question is, how can I modify the search to only return rows where the selectedId is an actual value of the array?

**EDIT**:
Given several sample rows with the following values for `ancestorIds`, and a `selectedId` value of 2...
`[1,2,26,42]`
`[2]`
`[2,42]`
`[42]`
`[22]`

...the code above is selecting every row, but I only want it to return the first three rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not full understand your example. If you want to have exact matching in the searching in 'ancestorIds' column you should just use `'eq'` operation instead of `'cn'`.

If you really need to implement very custom local searching method you can use the technique which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822685/315935).

If you need not so hardcore customization of local filtering you should describe your exact requirements more detailed.