# jqgrid Toolbar search on custom formatted column

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am loading JQGrid from an API, one of the data structures that I have for my grid is a JSON element formatted as such:

```
{"id":123,"name":"John Doe","username":"john.doe"}
```

The data is properly displayed in the grid, however if I try to type in the toolbar search, I do not get a match presumably because jqgrid still has the above JSON stored as an object.

A truncated version of my grid is as follows:

```
$('#test').jqGrid({
...
loadonce: true,
datatype: 'local',
colModel: [
{name:'test', index:'test', label:'Test', formatter:customFormatter}
],
...
});

function customFormatter (cellvalue,options) {
                return cellvalue.name;
}
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822302/how-to-do-local-search-on-formatted-column-value-in-jqgrid) that seems to address this very matter, however I am struggling to get my head around as to how to use this for a JSON object. Once the grid is loaded, I don't see a reason as to why the local data should be anything other than string (Until the grid is reloaded).

Comment: I also attempted to use JSON dot notation and I still have the same issues:

`{name:'test.name', index:'test', label:'Test'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stumbling upon the JSON dot notation in the docs, and adding it to the index this now works:

```
colModel: [
    {name:'test.name', index:'test.name', label:'Test'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose `name` property of `colModel` which corresponds the names of the properties in the JSON input. So it's native to use just

```
colModel: [
    {name: "name", label: "Name"}
    {name: "username", label: "User Name"}
]
```

If you do need to remap some names in the JSON input to another names in the `colModel` you should use `jsonmap` property. For example

```
colModel: [
    {name: "test1", label: "Name", jsonmap: "name"}
    {name: "test2", label: "User Name", jsonmap: "username"}
]
```

The usage of `index` different as `name` is not possible in case of usage of `loadonce: true`. It is *not recommended* to use values of `name` property which have `.` or any other [meta-character](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#jq-primaryContent). The restriction exist because the `name` property will be used to build `id` property of many elements of the grid.